# Extract rows from data in R with conditions on features

Tags: r, select, rstudio

I have a dataset that I load in RStudio that contains 6 input features and 2 outputs, with 4000 obserations. I would like to build from this data, another dataset that contains fixed values of 5 input features, and only one input that varies. Let's say that my data is given by:

```
In1 In2 In3 In4 In5 In6 Out1 Out2
4    3   2   4   2   10  0.4  0.5
4    3   2   3   2   7   0.6  0.8
2    3   1   4   2   9   0.2  0.1
4    3   2   4   2   8   0.8  0.7
4    5   6   4   2   1   0.9  0.1
4    3   2   4   2   3   0.4  0.5
```

What I would like to obtain is (where all inputs are constant except In6)

```
In1 In2 In3 In4 In5 In6 Out1 Out2
4    3   2   4   2   10  0.4  0.5
4    3   2   4   2   8   0.8  0.7
4    3   2   4   2   3   0.4  0.5
```

How can I do that in R?
Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: how do you arrive at the fixed values in the second data frame?

Comment: I actually would like to know how can I get these using R..

Comment: Do you want the columns to be based on the mean, median etc of the cols in the first data frame?

Comment: Can it be any of the 6 inputs that remain constant or always columns 1 through 5?

Comment: Yes it can be one of the columns, not necessarily input 6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df = read.table(text = "
In1 In2 In3 In4 In5 In6 Out1 Out2
                4    3   2   4   2   10  0.4  0.5
                4    3   2   3   2   7   0.6  0.8
                2    3   1   4   2   9   0.2  0.1
                4    3   2   4   2   8   0.8  0.7
                4    5   6   4   2   1   0.9  0.1
                4    3   2   4   2   3   0.4  0.5
                ", header=T)

library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(In1,In2,In3,In4,In5) %>%  # for those variables
  mutate(n = n()) %>%                # count number of combination and add it as a column
  ungroup() %>%                      # forget the grouping
  filter(n == max(n)) %>%            # return the rows with the most popular combination
  select(-n)                         # remove the counts

# # A tibble: 3 x 8
#     In1   In2   In3   In4   In5   In6  Out1  Out2
#   <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <dbl> <dbl>
# 1     4     3     2     4     2    10   0.4   0.5
# 2     4     3     2     4     2     8   0.8   0.7
# 3     4     3     2     4     2     3   0.4   0.5
```

This approach assumes that you'll always have a winner combination and that you care only about that winner combination.

Comment: Thank you a lot, yes it worked!! Thank you a lot :)))!

Answer (score 1):

This produces the requested output from the input, but I don't know if it generalises to a broader case.

First, I define the data frame `df`

```
df <- read.table(text = "In1 In2 In3 In4 In5 In6 Out1 Out2
4    3   2   4   2   10  0.4  0.5
4    3   2   3   2   7   0.6  0.8
2    3   1   4   2   9   0.2  0.1
4    3   2   4   2   8   0.8  0.7
4    5   6   4   2   1   0.9  0.1
4    3   2   4   2   3   0.4  0.5", header = TRUE)
```

Then, I look for duplicated rows in columns 1 through 5.

```
df[duplicated(df[, 1:5])|duplicated(df[, 1:5], fromLast = TRUE),]

#   In1 In2 In3 In4 In5 In6 Out1 Out2
# 1   4   3   2   4   2  10  0.4  0.5
# 4   4   3   2   4   2   8  0.8  0.7
# 6   4   3   2   4   2   3  0.4  0.5
```

---

This tries all possible combinations of inputs. I find all possible combinations of the 5 columns from the 6 inputs.

```
col_combinations <- combn(1:6, 5)
```

Then, I test each.

```
apply(col_combinations, MAR = 2, 
      function(x)df[duplicated(df[, x])|duplicated(df[, x], fromLast = TRUE),])
```

As you can see, only one is successful.

```
# [[1]]
#   In1 In2 In3 In4 In5 In6 Out1 Out2
# 1   4   3   2   4   2  10  0.4  0.5
# 4   4   3   2   4   2   8  0.8  0.7
# 6   4   3   2   4   2   3  0.4  0.5
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] In1  In2  In3  In4  In5  In6  Out1 Out2
# <0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
# 
# [[3]]
# [1] In1  In2  In3  In4  In5  In6  Out1 Out2
# <0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
# 
# [[4]]
# [1] In1  In2  In3  In4  In5  In6  Out1 Out2
# <0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
# 
# [[5]]
# [1] In1  In2  In3  In4  In5  In6  Out1 Out2
# <0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
# 
# [[6]]
# [1] In1  In2  In3  In4  In5  In6  Out1 Out2
# <0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Unfortunately it didn't work on my data!

Comment: Can you clarify how it didn't work? Error? Incorrect output? If so, can you provide an example of how it fails?

Comment: The resulted data set contains different values of In1 to In6, it does not keep all inputs constant except In6.